# Pypsark isin variable assignment

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, isin

I have a PySpark dataframe with 50k records (dfa) and another with 40k records (dfb). In dfa, I want to create a new column tagging the 40k records in dfb with 'present' else 'not_present'.

I know pandas has syntax for this but I'm having trouble finding the PySpark syntax.

Input:
dfa

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| xyz | row |
| abc | row |
| def | row |

df2

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| xyz | row |
| abc | row |

Expected Output:

df3

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | row | present |
| abc | row | present |
| def | row | not_pre |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df3 = df1.join(df2.select('col1', F.lit('present').alias('col3')).distinct(), 'col1', 'left')
df3 = df3.fillna('not_pre', 'col3')
```

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('xyz', 'row'),
     ('abc', 'row'),
     ('def', 'row')],
    ['col1', 'col2']
)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('xyz', 'row'),
     ('abc', 'row')],
    ['col1', 'col2']
)

df3 = df1.join(df2.select('col1', F.lit('present').alias('col3')).distinct(), 'col1', 'left')
df3 = df3.fillna('not_pre', 'col3')

df3.show()
# +----+----+-------+
# |col1|col2|   col3|
# +----+----+-------+
# | xyz| row|present|
# | abc| row|present|
# | def| row|not_pre|
# +----+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well if in case you want to check using combination of both the columns.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

simpleData = [("xyz","row"), \
    ("abc","row"), \
    ("def","row")
  ]
columns= ["col1","col2"]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData, schema = columns)


simpleData2 = [("xyz","row"), \
    ("abc","row")
  ]
columns2= ["col1","col2"]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData2, schema = columns2)

joined = (df1.alias("df1").join(df2.alias("df2"),(col("df1.col1") == col("df2.col1")) & (col("df1.col2") == col("df2.col2")),"left"))
df = joined.select(col("df1.*"),col("df2.col1").isNotNull().cast("integer").alias("flag")).withColumn("col3",when(col('flag')==1,lit("present")).otherwise("not_present")).drop('flag')
df.show()
```

[image]